# sql join and count error

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, count

I am trying to count how many employees there are at certain stores and group by store code from 2 tables containing, 1-Emplyee.EMP_CODE,STORE_CODE Table and 2-STORE.store_code... 
(STORE tbl-does not contain EMP_CODE) SO I may not even be on the right track.

```
SELECT c.EMP_CODE,c.STORE_CODE,s.STORE_CODE,COUNT(c.EMP_CODE)
FROM EMPLOYEE c
LEFT OUTER JOIN STORE s
  on    c.STORE_CODE=s.STORE_CODE   
GROUP BY s.STORE_CODE
;
```

Keep Getting an error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column 'EMPLOYEE.EMP_CODE' is
>   invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states, you need to have all non-aggregate columns in your `GROUP BY`, from those that you are selecting.

**Option 1**: Add all of the non-aggregate columns to your `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT c.EMP_CODE,c.STORE_CODE,s.STORE_CODE,COUNT(c.EMP_CODE)
FROM EMPLOYEE c
LEFT OUTER JOIN STORE s
  on    c.STORE_CODE=s.STORE_CODE   
GROUP BY c.EMP_CODE,c.STORE_CODE,s.STORE_CODE;
```

**Option 2**: Remove all non-grouped columns from your original `SELECT`

```
SELECT s.STORE_CODE, COUNT(c.EMP_CODE)
FROM EMPLOYEE c
LEFT OUTER JOIN STORE s
  on    c.STORE_CODE=s.STORE_CODE   
GROUP BY s.STORE_CODE;
```

**Option 3**: Use a nested select to `COUNT(c.EMP_CODE)` and only `GROUP BY s.STORE_CODE`, while still being able to select all of the columns you want.  Something like:

```
SELECT c.EMP_CODE,c.STORE_CODE,s.STORE_CODE,A.Count_Emp
FROM EMPLOYEE c
LEFT OUTER JOIN STORE s
  on    c.STORE_CODE=s.STORE_CODE   
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT s.STORE_CODE, COUNT(c.EMP_CODE) as 'Count_Emp'
         FROM EMPLOYEE c
         LEFT OUTER JOIN STORE s
         ON c.STORE_CODE=s.STORE_CODE   
         GROUP BY s.STORE_CODE
                ) A on A.STORE_CODE = c.STORE_CODE;
```

Comment: Option 3: a correlated sub-select to count.

Comment: Note: this is not an all-encompassing list of options.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing all the columns from your GROUP BY Clause. That should fix it!